# Get Images from website

Tags: web-crawler

I need to download all images from a website to which I have username and password.
Say, website url is 
http://example.co.in/images/Photos/ABC123.jpg
in such a way there many images, my requirement is to download all images.
What can be done in Java, C++ or any programming language ?
Sample code will be helpful.
Thanks

Using following code to get image from Google website

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello World");

    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.co.in/images/google_favicon_128.png");
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
        out.write(buf, 0, n);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C://ABC//google1.jpg");
    fos.write(response);
    fos.close();

}}
```

Now I need help where I don't know name of images say all images with extension .jpg (*.jpg) and it should store in my folder as 1.jpg, 2.jpg and so on.
So how to get count of number of images and how to access their names in http://www.google.co.in/images/

Comment: You are looking for a [*crawler*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler). I recently used [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), and it is fairly simple to use.

Comment: Look for image tags, find the tags' URLs, compute the image URLs if necessary (e.g., relative links), retrieve via normal HTTP request. What's the actual issue?

Comment: I need count of images in images/ folder of website.
how to do using Java

Comment: @prathameshr: Your comments (and original tagging) says java, but the question says "java C++ or any other language" which is it?

Comment: @ amit its java only... but if any can help in C++ or any other language, they are welcome.

Comment: I used [Crawler4j](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j) for crawling site and all urls it finds and use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) to grab image using css selectors.  The guides and examples on this are great to follow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a **[*crawler*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler)**. I recently used **[scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)**, and it is fairly simple to use.

All you have to do is create your [Spider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html). It needs to generate [`Request`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) objects for each url you are encountering, and you can download the image in the page using an extra HTTP request to the image.

Follow the [tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html), it is really simple and leads you step by step, explaining you how to build your crawler, and providing a [code example](https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot) as well.

Note that scrapy works with python.

There is also **[crawl4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/) for java**. I am not personally familiar with it, but I have heard it is very simple one as well.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are comfortable in Java, you can try using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

They have [HtmlPage.getElementsByTagName("img")](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) method, which will give you the list of image tags in the HTML. Based on the result you can get the image src location and download the image from the URL using your test method.

You can also use other HTML parsers like [SimpleHTML Parser](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers), [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) etc for parsing HTML to get the image tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Linux user, have a look at the command line tool `wget`

As a Windows user you might use it via [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) (http://www.cygwin.com/)

Comment: I am Win user.
I need to do using Java

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a crawler. If you're going for Java, I would recommend using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse the HTML from websites. Combined with [commons.io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) you should be able to do this fairly easy.

If you want a full code example, you can take a look at a recent [project](https://github.com/Vannevelj/Web-Crawler/tree/master/WebCrawler2.0/src) I made that does exactly this.

Basically all you have to do is load all links from the `src` attribute of `img` tags and then download these images. You can provide extra parameters like image type or size, but that's up to your own discretion.

Answer (score -1):

Use [crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/) it's pretty easy web crawler library to work with.

On their sample demo shows how to grab urls contained within a page.

```
 List<WebURL> links = htmlParseData.getOutgoingUrls();
```

I wouldn't use byte streams to write a file.  You could can make a File object from a URI and then figure out how to write a file to disk.

```
File imageFile = new File( new URL("www.foo.someImage.jpg").toURI() );
```

Another possible solution is with ImageIO()

```
URL url = new URL("www.foo.someImage.jpg");

Image image = ImageIO.read(url);

if(image != null){
   ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",new File("file path to save");
}
```

Comment: The issue at hand isn't saving an image, it's retrieving all images from a given webpage.

Comment: Ouch for the down vote.  Getting urls from a page is super easy, left that out because libraries for web crawlers where already listed.